# FileNotFoundException inside a DLL

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, error-handling

I have a WinForms application that relies on a class library DLL. Inside the class library there is a method that opens a file. While working inside Visual Studio IDE if I provide the wrong file path I get a FileNotFoundException as expected.

Why if I run the app outside VisualStudio the exception is not thrown?

Thanks.

EDIT: The path does not exist on disk, it's wrong from any place/environment. The question is on why the exception can be seen inside VStudio IDE and not running the app from Bin/Release folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you use relative path which is proper when you are out side.
Also check CurrentDir while running inside MSVS

UPDATE:

May be you have a handler for the exception (try/catch). MSVS shows that there is an exception and it goes to handler (normal situation). Outside of MSVs it just goes to handler

Comment: Yes, you are right. Inside VStudio we have the Debug->Exceptions->CLR Exception active, this is the reason why we only get them inside VStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with different threads?
If you have a BeginInvoke, for example, and you don't have the associate EndInvoke, Exception may "get lost".

Comment: Please add some code, otherwise it's difficult to provide some help

Answer (score 0):

The working folder is different if you're running your app within VS. Try using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location to get your current working folder and base your file path on that.